# Back_insert_iterator return type

Tags: c++, stl

I am very new to C++ and the STL. My question is why the member function of back_insert_iterator for operator* () and operator++() returns *this? and why the iterator needs both member function?

Is the idea get from the following code fragment? (II: InputIterator, OI:OutputIterator).

```
template <typename II, typename OI>
OI my_copy (II b, II e, OI x) {
while (b != e) {
    *x = *b;
    ++b;
    ++x;}
return x;}
```

Any inputs are appreciated and thank you so much for reading my questions.

Comment: Have a read of:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
back_insert_iterator& operator*();
```

Just an assignment operation

It returns the iterator itself, which makes it possible to use code such as `*iter = value` to output (insert) the value into the underlying container.

The below one serves as an arithmetic operation

```
back_insert_iterator& operator++();
back_insert_iterator& operator++( int );
```

They make it possible for the expressions `*iter++=value and *++iter=value` to be used to output (insert) a value into the underlying container.

Additional question asked by  Ning Chang in comment

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int>> it(v);
    *it = 10; // it is equivalent to v.push_back(10);
     it = 99; // it is ALSO equivalent to v.push_back(99); 
    for (auto const & i : v) std::cout << i << " " ; //10 99
    return 0;
}
```

*it =10

calls/uses

```
back_insert_iterator& operator*()
    {   // pretend to return designated value
    return (*this);
    }
```

where as it = 99;

calls and uses

```
back_insert_iterator& operator=(typename _Container::value_type&& _Val)
    {   // push value into container
    container->push_back(_STD move(_Val));
    return (*this);
    }
```

So even though the behavior is same but the way of implementation is bit different

Comment: Big thanks. Can you please help to explain why the overloaded operator return a *this?

Comment: @Ning Chang 1  Please follow there is more info  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907677/whats-the-difference-between-iterator-and-back-insert-iterator

Comment: @Harion Singh Thank you so much. I read the [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907677 I have a question on why iterator operation got no effect on *, ++? I quoted the content of the comments from the link.std::vector<int> v; std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int>> it(v); *it = 10; // it is equivalent to v.push_back(10); it = 99; // it is ALSO equivalent to v.push_back(99); for (auto const & i : v) std::cout << i << " " ; //10 99 The usual iterator operations ++ and * on it has no effect.